# Setup a git bare repo on a windows apache server

Tags: windows, git, apache, git-push, git-clone

I need help in setting up a bare git repo on an apache web server. I followed the below instructions

```
$ cd /var/www/htdocs/
$ git clone --bare /path/to/git_project gitproject.git
$ cd gitproject.git
$ mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
$ chmod a+x hooks/post-update
```

I got these instructions from here 
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols.

I try to run

```
git clone "http://ip-addr/gitproject.git"
```

, but am not successful and neither the push command works. Do you have any suggestions on what to do next.

Comment: what user do zou run the commands as? any error messages?

Comment: so when I run the git clone command, nothing happens, it just hangs and exits in a while.

Answer (score 0):

At least try it without the double-quotes:

```
git clone http://ip-addr/gitproject.git
```

And if it still hangs, check the log of your Apache server, to see if it is contacted at all.